# I'm creating a stored procedure in PostgreSQL, but I get an error 'syntax error at or near "UPDATE"'

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a stored procedure that changes email address, but I keep getting an error.

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UPDATE"

```
CREATE FUNCTION change(
IN oldAddr VARCHAR(50),
IN newAddr VARCHAR(50)
) AS
UPDATE accounts
SET a_email = newAddr
WHERE a_email = oldAddr;
```

I copied this from the textbook, but I don't think it works on PostgreSQL.
Please teach me how to correct it!
Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
a_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
a_first_name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
a_last_name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
a_email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
a_password varchar(16) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it this way

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_account_email(
  IN oldAddr VARCHAR(50),
  IN newAddr VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INTEGER AS 
$$
DECLARE
  rcount INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
  UPDATE accounts
     SET a_email = newAddr
   WHERE a_email = oldAddr;
   GET DIAGNOSTICS rcount = ROW_COUNT;
   RETURN rcount;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Sample usage:

```
SELECT change_account_email('djohn@example.com', 'new@example.com');
```

Let's try it:

```
# INSERT INTO accounts VALUES(1, 'John', 'Doe', 'djohn@example.com', '*********');
INSERT 0 1

# SELECT change_account_email('djohn@example.com', 'new@example.com');
 change_account_email 
----------------------
                    1
(1 row)

# SELECT * FROM accounts;
 a_id | a_first_name | a_last_name |     a_email     | a_password 
------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+------------
    1 | John         | Doe         | new@example.com | *********
(1 row)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/54b36/2)** demo

Comment: Okay. Sorry, I am new here. Thank you again!